# Max brightness on NetBook

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

The maximum brightness on my NetBook isn't very bright.  Windows 7 is very bright on max, but for some reason, Ubuntu isn't.  Is th
ere any way to adjust the brightness past it's maximum setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open for edit the `/etc/grub/default` file with:

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Locate the value:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`

and change to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Save the file, then run: `sudo update-grub`

Reboot, and see if worked.

Comment: Seems to have worked.  It had a side benefit.  I was having an opposite effect with the dimming when inactive.  The display was very bright when inactive, but dimmed as soon as I touched the touchpad.  This seems to have been fixed as  well. And for what it's worth, I left the "quiet" argument in as well.  Doesn't seem to have made a difference.  Thanks a bunch!