# Max Brightness in ubuntu lower when compared to windows

Tags: 14.04, laptop, brightness, thinkpad

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my (new) ThinkPad Edge330. Everything worked quite well so far.

I've noticed that the screen wasn't that bright and was a bit disappointed of the ThinkPad, but then I realized that the brightness was much better on a parallel windows 7 installation I did later on.

I already used this tip:
[Max brightness on NetBook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220584/max-brightness-on-netbook)

I did increase the brightness to an acceptable level (could be the actual max. brightness, or is there a way to increase it even further?)
But now unfortunately I cannot change the screen brightness at all anymore. Not by using the FN keys or in the system settings.

---

Actually I Just fixed it,

1. By adding the options suggested in [Max brightness on NetBook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220584/max-brightness-on-netbook)
2. Creating a file: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf 
   with the content: 
   Section "Device"
   Identifier "card0"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
   BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection

Now everything works quite well, I can access the maximum brightness, brightness control works and additionally I can switch of the screen completely (This was not possible before)